# Regex split on particular length digit

Tags: python-3.x, regex

I have a string which contains 6 digit number and more than 6 digit number. I want to split it exactly at 6 digit number. Here is my code.

```
txt = 'Hello.this.is232323dsSDdsadasd3434343'
split = re.split(r'(\d{6}?)', txt)
print(split)
```

But my output is like its splitting the 7 digit number too.

```
['Hello.this.is', '232323', 'dsSDdsadasd', '343434', '3']
```

I don't want to split the other numbers only 6 digit number.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2):

You may use negative lookbehind and negative lookahead to ensure there are no surrounding digits.

```
re.split(r"(?<!\d)(\d{6})(?!\d)", txt)
```

Output:

```
['Hello.this.is', '232323', 'dsSDdsadasd3434343']
```

Comment: Ah ha! Thanks, I knew lookarounds would work but couldn't get the right combination and didn't consider that the first span of 6 might fail but the second would succeed :D